# Metro Apps TimeZoneInfo alternative

Tags: c#, datetime, microsoft-metro

I would like to make a simple calculation but not sure how to approach this using c# for metro apps since TimeZoneInfo does not have most of the functionality it used to for other type of applications not metro.

How can I convert my current machine time to UTC time? It is probably something simple that was now made complicated and I do not understand.

Was trying to use

```
TimeZoneInfo time = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
```

Which is where the server is, and then trying to convert my machine time to that, but no luck since I do not have that functionality. I checked out those WINRT something libraries, but I do not really like those. Is there an easier way? (keep in mind the current machine time could be in Australia, Europe, United States.

Maybe I can get the offset of utc from local (but how to I get the time in central?) and then the utc offset of central. I am not sure it is confusing.

Comment: How about [DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the local timezone with TimeZoneInfo.Local . What you can't get is arbitrary other timezones: only local and Utc.

TimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset will give the time difference between the current time zone and UTC.

```
TimeZoneInfo local = TimeZoneInfo.Local; 
TimeZoneInfo utc = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
Debug.WriteLine("Local TimeZone is {0} offset from UTC:{2}", local,utc,local.BaseUtcOffset);

DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
Debug.WriteLine("It is now {0} (UTC: {1})", localTime, utcTime);
```

Results:

```
Local TimeZone is (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) offset from UTC:-08:00:00
It is now 10/09/2014 14:59:07 (UTC: 10/09/2014 21:59:07)
```